# I want to trigger an API call when the application is killed(Android Kotlin XML)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, foreground-service

I am creating an conversation application.
So, when I first enter the screen I will trigger an API mentioning that the session has started.
In the same way, if the user either moves to another screen / if the application is completely destroyed, then I want to end the session.
I have tried using a foreground service, but it is not working as expected.

Could someone please give the best solution for my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to end a session when the user moves to another screen, override `onStop()`. It is called every time an Activity goes off screen. And you can restore the session in `onStart()`.

Comment: What about triggering the API when the application is destroyed? @Tenfour04

Comment: You can override `onDestroy()` but it’s not guaranteed to be called since if the system is destroying your app, it wants to do it as fast as possible to reclaim memory. I don’t know what it would mean to “end a session” if your app is destroyed. If it’s destroyed, it’s gone. It can’t have a session. If you’re hoping to communicate with some server to tell it to end a session in that situation, I’m pretty sure you can’t do that reliably. Destroying an app means tearing it down to stop whatever it might be doing and free resources so your app doesn’t get to do extra stuff in that situation.

Comment: What I would do is periodically tell the server that the session should stay open. If you app gets destroyed, then the server will stop receiving these messages so it can declare a session ended if a stay-open message isn’t received in time. So maybe it declares the session closed up to ten seconds late if your interval is ten seconds for example, but that’s not a big deal.